# "Predicate NodeAffinity failed"

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

I have a GKE cluster which I updated to "v1.19.11-gke.2101".

In that cluster we are running tons of pods which have node selectors like this:

```
      nodeSelector:
        cloud.google.com/gke-nodepool: default-pool
```

Since I updated the cluster, from time to time the pods are entering in:

```
Status:         Failed
Reason:         NodeAffinity"
```

With these status events:

```
  Warning  NodeNotReady  55m   node-controller                                            Node is not ready
  Warning  NodeAffinity  53m   kubelet, gke-ef-gke-cluster-front-default-pool-bbda0bbf-t4js  Predicate NodeAffinity failed
```

The thing is that even though the status is "fail", other pods are successfully scheduled so there is no "real issue" just an annoying red flag which I would like to get rid of.

I saw that there are several issues closed in the kubernets GitHub repo mentioning this and claiming that is fixed:

- https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/100467
- https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/99336

But the problem is still there in GKE 1.19.11. AFAIK gke has its own Kubernetes implementation so.. does any body know if it is actually solved in a specific GKE version? which one? And even if not.. Any idea of how to get rid of annoying flag without having to manually/periodically delete the stuck pods?

Thanks in advance, any help will be more than welcome.

Comment: Has your issue been resolved? If yes, can you post the procedure you've followed as a solution and accept it?

Comment: We haven't resolved the issue yet, we are waiting for the GKE 1.20 version become stable before upgrading it.

Comment: Does the given answer helped?

Comment: I haven't try the solution yet cause version 1.20 is not stable, that's why I haven't answered neither marked the solution.

Answer (score 2):

This issue is affecting GKE Clusters under the ‘1.19.11’ version, so upgrading them to ‘1.20.x’ would be a workaround if you are using preemptible Nodes. Please take into consideration that this issue is being currently worked on in order to provide a fixed solution.

Be aware that, although you may experience delay in the data processing, there should be no impact on the workload.

- There is no alternate method for removing the failed pods other than the manual deletion, but they can re-appear as the issue has not been fixed.
- Opting-out of preemptible nodes temporarily as this issue happens rarely on regular nodes.

You can track the updates in this new [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/185362914)